# Как исправить баг со слайдером?

Tags: jquery, slider, html, javascript, css

Долго уже мучаюсь, не могу исправить баг с отображением слайдера.
Когда запускаешь сайт http://test.webjay.ru , переходишь на на таб2 (кнопка "Полутеплые Slidors"), то почему отображается криво (смотрите рисунок)?
Когда обновляешь страницу, то проблема как бы исчезает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас там проблема не со слайдером, а с картинками, они разного размера. А когда в css селектору .slide img   max-width меняешь на width - все красиво (ну, насколько это возможно сказать, что красиво, во всяком случае не криво).

Comment: а как изображения настроить,им размеры как задавать,чтобы криво не смотрелись и не скукоживались,просто есть изображение 378px*134px и 
285px*183px.Если задать четкую ширину и длину в px они кривыми становятся

Comment: Поймите, что тут либо обрезать надо, либо растягивать. Что то, что то без потерь не пройдет. Проще все изначально одного размера сделать  сделать.